# How can I add an icon in the Form Builder G10 program?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, formbuilder

I tried to type the file name but it didn't work.
I tried to type the image path but it didn't work.

Comment: Add icon ... where?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Images in a running Forms application must use virtual paths and not physical paths.  This is very much like a web page.  In other words, you images must be hosted from a location that is virtually mapped on the server or contain in a JAR file.  Also, the images must of a Java compatible format (e.g. gif, jpg, png, etc).  You cannot use ICO files in web forms.